# GEOIP SCRIPT Forwarding Part not working

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation

I have a very small script but there is error in it, hoping this will take someone 2 minutes to easily fix.

What I am doing...  I have website, call it website.com.  There is link on homepage.  Link will take person to website.com/link

On page website.com/link is script.  Script is to using geoip to find out if person is from US, England, or Other.

What I want it to do is forward the person to URL1 if they are from US, forward person to URL2 if they are from England, or forward person to URL3 if they are from anywhere else.

The part of script that is not working is the forwarding part.  I know the GEOIP script part works correctly because I tested this with IMAGE1, IMAGE2, and IMAGE3 and it worked fine.  So issue is changing script so it forwards person along to another URL.

Here is script.

```
<?php

require_once(ABSPATH.'geoip.inc');
$gi = geoip_open(ABSPATH.'GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
$country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);
if($country=='US')
    echo '<?php
header( 'Location: http://www.google.com'; ) ;
?>';
elseif($country=='GB')
    echo '<?php
header( 'Location: http://www.bing.com'; ) ;
?>';
else
    echo '<?php
header( 'Location: http://www.yahoo.com'; ) ;
?>';

?>
```

Comment: `echo '<?php` - what's this?!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is enough to redirect:

```
<?php
require_once(ABSPATH.'geoip.inc');

$gi = geoip_open(ABSPATH.'GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
$country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);

if ($country=='US') 
    header('Location: http://www.google.com');
elseif ($country=='GB') 
    header('Location: http://www.bing.com');
else 
    header('Location: http://www.yahoo.com');
?>
```

Comment: 1. what returns `print_r($country)`? 2. do you see any errors? 3. do you have any output before this part, e.g. `echo`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's add exit().

```
<?php
    require_once(ABSPATH.'geoip.inc');

    $gi = geoip_open(ABSPATH.'GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
    $country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    geoip_close($gi);

    if ($country=='US')
    {
    header('Location: http://www.google.com');
    exit();
  }
    elseif ($country=='GB') 
    {
        header('Location: http://www.bing.com');
    exit();
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: http://www.yahoo.com');
    }
?>
```